# Analytics data does not shows up in Firebase console

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

My problem is about the analytics feature of Firebase. I set up my project with the help of react-native-firebase.

If I call: firebase.analytics(); which is provided by react-native-firebase no analytics data shows up in my Firebase console.

Why is that happening?

Info:
  - I set up all as described in the official docs

Answer (score 0):

It takes a few hours. In my case, it takes like 4 hours or something like that. 
If you want to check out other features or check if Firebase is working for your app, you can force a crash, and see it in the Crash panel, cause this works almost real time.
Or you can send a notification to all users, this should work too, and it is faster than waiting for 4h or more to see if it is working really.